# Создать папки для Activity

Tags: android, android-studio

Делаю приложение первый раз и мало что знаю. Возможно ли создать папки, чтобы рассортировать activity?[image]

Comment: создать папки возможно. Правой кнопкой на нужном пакете-родителе и `New`=>`Package`

Answer (score 4):

В `Project` раскрываешь дерево папки `java`. Затем ПКМ нажимаешь на пакет-родитель, New -> Package и пишешь название нового пакета.